# Vue: String interpolation within a string?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following block but I want to remove the hardcoded URL:

```
import { MY_SITE_URL } from './constants';

foo() {
   return this.capitalize('My site is <a href="www.mysite">here</a>')
}
```

I have a constant that I want to use and my alternative is now:

```
**Alternative 1**


foo() {
   return this.capitalize('My site is <a href="' +
        myUrl
        '" here');
}

computed {
    myUrl() {
       return MY_SITE_URL
    }
}
```

How can I do this without using a computed property and just directly using interpolation with the constant inside that string?

Comment: best to avoid html in the value and just place that in the template, then you could use a global mixin, plugin or store, i.e `$config.site_url`, `$store.state.config.site_url`

Comment: additionally this.capitalize can/should be done with css or changed at the source

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the computed prop just to return a constant. Instead, use the constant directly. Also consider using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (with backticks instead of quotes) to improve readability:

```js
const MY_SITE_URL = 'https://example.com'

export default {
  computed: {
    foo() {
      return this.capitalize(`My site is <a href="${MY_SITE_URL}">here</a>`)
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWpGgxm)